# How to get values from data grid view in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I tried with this code..

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagridItemEntry.RowCount; i++)
{
     int a = Convert.ToInt32(datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
     int b = Convert.ToInt32(datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
     int c = a * b;
     datagridItemEntry.SelectedRows[i].Cells[6].Value = c.ToString();
}
```

I want value of cell 4 & 5 to be get multiplied and the result should be reflect in cell 6..
Nothing is happening with the above code..
Help me with the proper code..

Comment: on which event of datagrid you are putting this code? Try to replace the SelectedRows[i] to be Rows[i]...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be here

```
 datagridItemEntry.SelectedRows[i].Cells[6].Value = c.ToString();
```

Replace `.SelectedRows` to `.Rows`

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagridItemEntry.RowCount; i++)
{
     int a = Convert.ToInt32(datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
     int b = Convert.ToInt32(datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
     int c = a * b;
     datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = c.ToString();
}
```